# How to start syncing and check status of Remote Daemon Node using monero-javascript npm package?

Tags: daemon, monero-wallet-rpc

I am using monero-javascript library to make a web app. When, I change the remote node, how can I start syncing my existing wallet with new Remote node.

Also when I do:

curl http://node.moneroworld.com:18089/json_rpc -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"get_connections"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'

I am getting following response:

{
"error": {
"code": -32601,
"message": "Method not found"
},
"id": "0",
"jsonrpc": "2.0"
}.

Please help me understand the flow

Answer (score 1):

You can use [setDaemonConnection()](https://moneroecosystem.org/monero-javascript/MoneroWallet.html#setDaemonConnection) to change the wallet's daemon endpoint using monero-javascript.